# ERROR #98123 WEBPACK: Generating development JavaScript bundle failed - unexpected token

Tags: npm, webpack, gatsby

I have cloned my repository an then install all packages via npm. When i try to start mu program with `gatsby develop` i get this error in all files in `templates` directory.

[image]

I've already cleared chache, deleted `node_modules` and `public` folders, re-install packages and so on, but nothing worked.

This is is info, which I get from `gatsby info`:

```
  System:
    OS: macOS 11.1
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.0.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.0.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.13.0 - ~/.npm-global/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.0.0/bin/npm
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 87.0.4280.141
    Firefox: 78.0.2
    Safari: 14.0.2
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^2.30.1 => 2.31.1
    gatsby-awesome-pagination: ^0.3.6 => 0.3.6
    gatsby-image: ^2.5.0 => 2.10.0
    gatsby-plugin-eslint: ^2.0.8 => 2.0.8
    gatsby-plugin-fontawesome-css: ^1.0.0 => 1.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^2.6.1 => 2.11.0
    gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms: ^4.5.0 => 4.9.0
    gatsby-plugin-offline: ^3.4.0 => 3.9.0
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^3.4.0 => 3.9.0
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^2.8.0 => 2.13.1
    gatsby-plugin-styled-components: ^3.5.0 => 3.9.0
    gatsby-plugin-typography: ^2.10.0 => 2.11.0
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^2.5.0 => 2.10.0
    gatsby-transformer-remark: ^2.12.0 => 2.15.0
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^2.6.0 => 2.11.0
```

Does anyone have similar problem, or know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of dependencies or configuration, you have a typo in your project. It seems that somewhere in your JavaScript files (maybe in the `templates` folder) you have a `.` (dot) that is breaking your code.

To enable optional chaining in any JavaScript project, since it's not a standard feature, you need to:

- Install the dependency ([`@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining)):

  ```
  npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining
  ```

  Or:

  ```
  yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining --dev
  ```
- Enable it in your Babel configuration. In Gatsby, you can create a `babel.config.js` (or `.babelrc`) in the root of your project to [customize Babel's configuration](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/babel/):

  ```
  {
     "plugins": [
       ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"]
     ],
     "presets": [
       [
         "babel-preset-gatsby",
         {
           "targets": {
             "browsers": [">0.25%", "not dead"]
           }
         }
       ]
     ]
  }
  ```

---

Fixed by:

> problem was `my package-lock.json`. After we fixed it, everything works
> properly :) nevermind

Comment: that `.` (dot) is there because of optional chaining 
`const {frontmatter, html} = data?.markdownRemark`

Comment: Have you installed the plugin? Non-standard ECMA features needs to be installed via Babel in the configuration file

Comment: I have just pulled master branch from origin and installed all packages from `package.json`.  Its very strange because a week ago everything worked perfectly.

Comment: problem was my package-lock.json. After we fixed it, everything works properly :) nevermind, thanks for help

Comment: Your're welcome. If you don't mind, I've edited the post if someone finds it helpful